# Cписок на флексбоксах

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend, flexbox

Как на flexbox сделать список вида.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура по коду:

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="font-weight-bold">Server:</div>
  <div class="column2">8sjf0-s89d-eiwe-3892k0s</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="font-weight-bold">Host Name:</div>
  <div class="column2">TIGRA</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="font-weight-bold">OS Type:</div>
  <div class="column2">WINDOWS</div>
</div>
 <div class="d-flex">
  <div class="font-weight-bold">IP Address:</div>
  <div class="column2">192.111.11</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Это имелось в виду?

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.card{
  width:300px;
  max-width:100%;
  border:2px solid;
}
.card__row{
  display:flex;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
}
.card__row:last-child{
  border-bottom:none;
}
.card__cell{
  padding:0 5px;
}
.card__cell:first-child{
  padding-right:20px;
  flex:0 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
}
.card__cell:not(:first-child){
  flex:1 1 auto;
}
.font-weight-bold{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card__row">
      <div class="card__cell font-weight-bold">Server:</div>
      <div class="card__cell">8sjf0-s89d-eiwe-3892k0s</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card__row">
      <div class="card__cell font-weight-bold">Host Name:</div>
      <div class="card__cell">TIGRA</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card__row">
      <div class="card__cell font-weight-bold">OS Type:</div>
      <div class="card__cell column2">WINDOWS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card__row">
      <div class="card__cell font-weight-bold">IP Address:</div>
      <div class="card__cell">192.111.11</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Поведение должно быть вот таким. Как в таблице. Набросал вариант. https://codepen.io/pikiviki/pen/aqxyVL

Comment: @Oleg Ovcharenko , в таком случае без задания ширины ячейки не обойтись. Почему не использовать `display:table` ?

Comment: Геннадий, если задавать display:table то если мы в последнюю верхнюю ячейку занесем длинный текст без пробелов типа (WWWW....)текст будет вылезать и все ломать. Если задать table-layout: fixed я получу поведение такое же как и у вас с случае с flex-box.